# onchange event iof javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on this from hours and still coudn't figure it out. this is really frustrating this simple code is also not working now.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript'>
function pp(){
document.getElementById("ppimg").src = document.getElementById("pp").value;

alert('burah');

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post">
<input onchange="pp()" type="file"  name="pp" >



 <input type="submit" >

 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

help please or I will need psychiatrist now

Comment: Put your `<script>` as the last element of `<body>`.

Comment: Where is the element with the id `ppimg`?!!

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. 
With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. 
This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) -- Specifically, you should check the developer console's output.

Comment: Where is the element with id "ppimg" and where is the element with id "pp"? Also, your <script> tag has deprecated syntax, use <script type="text/javascript"></script> or just <script></script> isntead.

Comment: The event itself works well, but you can't read the value of input type of file, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file . And as others have already said, you need the elements with the corresonding ids, name attribute is not id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are having the name field of the input tag same as the function name. Change your name tag with anything else and it should work.

Checkout this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
<input  type="file"  name="ppasd" id="pip" onchange="pp()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function pp() {
        alert('hi')
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code work for you.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function inform(){
        var filename = document.getElementById('myFile').value;
        alert(filename);
    }
    </script>
    <form name="form1">
    Please choose a file.
    <input type="file" name="uploadbox" size="35" onChange='inform()' id="myFile">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If this code work as you want please comment here it work or not. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some kind of reference problem with `pp`. Use the following code and it should work

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post">
<input onchange="callback()" type="file"  id="pp" >



 <input type="submit" >

 </form>
 <script language='javascript'>
    function callback(){
    document.getElementById("ppimg").src = document.getElementById("pp").value;

    alert('burah');

    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S It is a good practice to add javascript code at the end of the html.

P.S 2 it will still get an error because there is no element with id `ppimg`

I hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

that's not working ? 
that's because you use function after put element
so do this instead :

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form  method="post">
<input onchange="pp()" type="file"  name="pp" >

<img id="ppimg"/>
 
 <input type="submit" >

 </form>
 <script language='javascript'>
function pp(){
document.getElementById("ppimg").src = document.getElementById("pp").value;

alert('burah');

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and if it's hard !
you can change pp() to pp;

Comment: Your code doesn't work, and reference to undefined element `ppimg`

Comment: sorry i'm forget i fixed it